# C# ASP.NET ajax通信で大量のHTMLが戻ってくる

Tags: javascript, c#, html, ajax, model-view-controller

MVC初心者です。
作業スペースはローカルです。

## View

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/aaa/bbb",
        data: { selectService: sendId },
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
```

...

## コントローラー

```
[HttpPost]
public string bbb(string selectService)
{
    var msg = "aaa";
    return msg;
}
```

普段動いていた方法です。
何かをしてしまったのか、急に任意の文字列ではなく関係ないHTMLのソースが戻ってくるようになりました。

それまではコントローラー側にはブレイクポイントを貼って中身を確認できたりしていたのですが、それも引っかからなくなりました。
ajaxの通信自体は成功しているらしくサクセスの方に入ります。（アラートは動く）
エラー側は無反応です。

何が考えられるでしょうか…。

Comment: タイトルにVBとありますが、本文ではC#になっているので無視してよいのでしょうか

Comment: すみません！おっしゃられる通りミスです！

Answer (score 2):

おそらくASP.NET側で何らかのエラーが発生し、リダイレクトによりエラーページやログインページなどが表示されているのだと思われます。

まずは返されるHTMLやサーバー側のエラーログを確認してください。IIS Expressでデバッグしているのであれば、Visual Studioで例外を確認することもできます。またIIS上であってもWeb.configで設定すれば例外のログがエラーページに表示されるようになります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
確認したところ、戻ってきている値はログイン画面のようでした。
昨晩、プロジェクトのRole管理の方法が変わったみたいで、それでかもしれません。

試しにプロジェクトを昨晩のマージ前に戻して試したところ、正常な値が戻ってきました。
権限を管理している方が本日確認取れる状態ではないので明日確認してみたいと思います。